# how to concatenate files in the subdirectory iteratively

Tags: shell, foreach

I have a bunch of directories, in each directory I have bunch of sub directories, in each sub directory I have 1 files named `x1` and *might* have `y1` `z1` as well.

I want to have a shell script that for each directory, goes through sub directories and concatenate all the `x1`s to one file and also all the `y1`s and all the `z1`s.

I have tried

```
cat ./*/*.x1 >test
```

I don't know how does it work with for each

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: In what order do you want the files concatenated?  Do you want to merge the y1 and z1 in with the x1 files as you descend through the directories, or do you want to collect first all the x1 files, and the others last?

Comment: I want to concatenate all the x1s in all directories  also all y1s and z1s respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `zsh` this `for` loop work:

```
for dir in *(/); do
  cat "$dir"/*.x1 > "$dir"/combined.x1
  [[ -n "$dir"/*.y1 ]] && cat "$dir"/*.y1 > "$dir"/combined.y1
  [[ -n "$dir"/*.z1 ]] && cat "$di"r/*.z1 > "$dir"/combined.z1
done
```

#### Update

For `bash` it seems you only need to update the `dir` pattern:

```
for dir in */; do
  cat "$dir"/*.x1 > "$dir"/combined.x1
  [[ -n "$dir"/*.y1 ]] && cat "$dir"/*.y1 > "$dir"/combined.y1
  [[ -n "$dir"/*.z1 ]] && cat "$di"r/*.z1 > "$dir"/combined.z1
done
```

Comment: Try `find "$path" -type d` if you need to recurse into nested directories.

Comment: It that case the directory names should be quoted, see answer.